# How to give multiple users on one computer access to run ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS in my home directory as an administer user. When other users, even with admin privilege, try to run ros commands, they receive the command can not be found message. Is there anyway that I give other users access to run ROS using my software?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38052/how-to-give-multiple-users-on-one-computer-access-to-run-ros?/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ktysai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41908/ktysai/) on 2020-11-25**:
On Ubuntu 18, ROS Melodic I have the same problem. On the same machine I need to connect two different users and both of them to run ROS without interfering to each other.

Any new developments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way is to install the binary packages (assuming you are running Ubuntu).

*Update*: Do not try sharing access to source trees. Only one user should run rosmake within a working copy. Users should each create their own separate working copies when doing shared development. Synchronize those changes via normal source repository commits and updates.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to configure the .bashrc file of the other user the same way as yours to let them find the path to the executables.  Also make sure that the executable files have the permissions correctly set to let other users to execute them.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) with karma: 188 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-05**:
While this might work in cases where users just have to execute nodes, it won't if users try to call rosmake unless all shared ROS packages contain a ROS_NOBUILD.

**Comment by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) on 2012-07-05**:
You are right.  I wasn't thinking about rosmake.  Building packages might be a problem.